# How to reformat strings denoting year and month in different columns of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, reformat

I have a data frame in `R` which has bunch of columns out of which two columns are denoting year and month period. I want to reformat these two columns thereby forming a single column with a different format of year_month. The current structure data frame `df1` is:

```
... | ... | year | month | ... | ...  
... | ... | 2000 |  P01  | ... | ... 
... | ... | 2000 |  P02  | ... | ... 
... | ... | 2000 |  P03  | ... | ...  
... | ... | 2000 |  P04  | ... | ... 
... | ... | 2000 |  P05  | ... | ... 
 .  |  .  |  .   |  .    |  .  |  .
 .  |  .  |  .   |  .    |  .  |  .
```

As can be seen the month column of data frame has letter `P` in front of each month number. Now I want to remove this letter `P` reformat the month number to denote month name instead of number (like Jan. for 01, Feb for 02) and then join this with year column so as to form a single column with month and year data in it. Thus I want something like this:

```
... | ... | month_year | ... | ...  
... | ... |  Jan. 2000 | ... | ... 
... | ... |  Feb. 2000 | ... | ... 
... | ... |  Mar. 2000 | ... | ...  
... | ... |  Apr. 2000 | ... | ... 
... | ... |  May. 2000 | ... | ... 
 .  |  .  |      .     |  .  |  .
 .  |  .  |      .     |  .  |  .
```

How can I reformat the two columns and club them into one column?

Comment: `library(zoo); transform(df1, yearmon = as.yearmon(paste0(year, sub("P", "-", month))))` creates a data frame with a new column of class `"yearmon"`.

Comment: Oh common, I was just going to post this :)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for the answer. But how do I put a `.` after month name like as in `Jan. 2000`. I tried to put it inside `paste0()` as in `paste0(year, sub("P", "-", month),".")` but nothing happens

Comment: If `df2` is the data frame above then `format(df2$yearmon, "%b. %Y")` .

Comment: @David, If you post your solution I will delete my comments.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, you have solved it all. I think you should post it, if only to promote your excellent package

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I did `df2 <- transform(df1, yearmon = as.yearmon(paste0(year, sub("P", "-", month))))` and then I did `df3 <- format(df2$yearmon, "%b. %Y")` but the `format()` deleted my other columns from the original data frame

Comment: @JasonDonnald, common, you owerwirited your data set. Do `library(zoo); df2 <- transform(df1, yearmon = as.yearmon(paste0(year, sub("P", "-", month)))); df2$yearmon <- format(df2$yearmon, "%b. %Y")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck and David Arenbug my mistake! thanks for the help. it works now. If any of your two could post the comment as a solution then I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.yearmon` from "zoo" along with `format`.

Transferring the comments to an answer with an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = 2000, month = c("P01", "P02", "P03", "P04"))
#   year month
# 1 2000   P01
# 2 2000   P02
# 3 2000   P03
# 4 2000   P04

library(zoo)
df2 <- transform(df1, yearmon = as.yearmon(paste0(year, sub("P", "-", month))))
df2$yearmon <- format(df2$yearmon, "%b. %Y")
df2
#   year month   yearmon
# 1 2000   P01 Jan. 2000
# 2 2000   P02 Feb. 2000
# 3 2000   P03 Mar. 2000
# 4 2000   P04 Apr. 2000
```